# XPath HTML finding nodes

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to try to find HTML 'A' nodes that have a href attribute that contains a certain string, in my case the string '/groups/':

```
HtmlNodeCollection groups = source.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/groups/')]");
```

Although the source code contains about 20 such nodes my code above is returning none which leads me to believe maybe I'm doing it incorrectly.

Is what I'm doing correct, and if not how can I select nodes that have a certain attribute that has a value that contains a certain string?

Comment: Please add the xml you're targeting

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is seems to be correct as for me.

You don't post your source document (or at least a part of it). So, I'll be guessing.

The thing is, xpath is not cool for case insensitive comparison. If you have an `<a>` tag with  `href` attribute that contains e.g. `/Groups/` or `/GROUPS/`, it won't be matched. There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8474109/102112) for this:

`//a[contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '/groups/')]`

As another option you could use LINQ with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

```
source.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
    .Where(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty)
                   .IndexOf("/groups/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
);
```