# ruby cucumber xpath contains "or" operator

Tags: ruby, xpath, cucumber

I am trying to work on an xpath for a pdf text.here is what I have

```
 cell(:x, :xpath => "//table//td[contains(.,'pdf')]")
```

what I am looking for is the proper way to make the 'pdf' non-case sensitive so it can be 'pdf' or 'PDF'

Here is what I've tried

```
cell(:commission_statement, :xpath => "//table//td[contains(.,'pdf'|'PDF')]")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [case insensitive xpath contains() possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8474031/841064)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:xpath => "//table/td[contains(.,'pdf') or contains(.,'PDF')]"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this xpath:

```
"//table//td[contains(.,'pdf')] | //table//td[contains(.,'PDF')]"
```

alternative solution:

```
"//td[contains(translate(., 'PDF', 'pdf'), 'pdf')]"
```

what translate does:

translate(string1,string2,string3)

Converts string1 by replacing the characters in string2 with the characters in string3

Example: translate('12:30','30','45')
Result: '12:45'

Example: translate('12:30','03','54')
Result: '12:45'

Example: translate('12:30','0123','abcd')
Result: 'bc:da'