# How to match element by text ignoring case?

Tags: regex, xpath, web, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

For example, I have an element

```
<div>TestMessage<div>
```

How do I get this element by 'testmessage' text?

Next options don't work:

```
//div[contains(., 'testmessage')]
//div[matches(text(),'testmessage','i')]
//div[lower-case(text())='testmessage'] 
//div[lower-case(.)='testmessage']
```

Comment: I googled, none of them works. Even translate.

Comment: My bad, I used `//text([contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'test')]` instead of `/html/body//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'test')]`. Thank you.

Comment: For the record, `matches()` and `lower-case()` require XPath 2.0.  Failure with those and success with `translate()` indicate that your XPath library does not support XPath 2.0.  Answers for both are included in [**case insensitive xpath contains() possible?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible), so I recommend this be closed a duplicate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly:

```
/html/body//text()[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'test')]
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible)