# XPath for next/sibling/following HTML element?

Tags: html, xml, r, xpath, web-scraping

In the following HTML code, I have two nested `<href>` links:

```
<a href="/cgi-bin/WebOb/mamool/8.2">
<img width="12" border="0" align="ABSMDIDDLE" height="7" src="/WebOb/mamool/Frameworks/fig.gif">
Click me for more info
</a>
<table border="1" size="2" font="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<font size="2">
<a name="179"></a>
    <a href="/cgi-bin/WebOb/mamool/8.2.44">
    <img width="12" border="0" align="ABSMDIDDLE" height="7" src="/WebOb/mamool/Frameworks/myfig.gif">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#d6e2ff">
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I can easily find the XPath for the first `<href>` link like this:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Click me for more info')]
```

Now I am wondering how to find the next `<href>` without searching, just say something like `.next()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next sibling element can be selected using the `following-sibling` axis:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Click me for more info')]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

would select the `table` element in your example.

If you want to select the next `a` element in the document, use the `following` axis:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Click me for more info')]/following::a[1]
```

Comment: just a quick qestion @kjhughes, how about if I have two href links which both contain 'Click me for more info', how should I select the first one, is this correct? //a[contains(text(), 'Click me for more info')][1]/following::a[1]

Comment: To select a second "Click me for more info" `a`, use `//a[contains(text(), 'Click me for more info')][2]`.

Comment: Hi @kjhughes , I just have a question on this. Is there anyway to make the "contains" function independent from capital or small letters. For example in the above case I want to detect both "Click me for more info" and also "cLicK ME for more Info". Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes:  See  [XPath 2.0 case-insensitive contains()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23388974/290085)  or, if you're stuck with XPath 1.0 see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8474552/290085) .