# Check if a page contains a certain text

Tags: html, xml, xpath

How can I find a text, or rather make sure it exists,  on an html page regardless where it's located and what html tags it's surrounded by and **its case**? I just know a text and I want to make sure a page contains it and the text is visible.

Comment: `'text' in response.body`

Comment: with xpath: `//*[contains(., "text")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and the text is visible

This part is a crucial one - *in order to determine element's visibility reliably, you would need the page rendered*. Let's automate a real browser with `selenium`, get the element having the desired text and check if the element is displayed. Example in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


desired_text = "Desired text"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")

try:
    is_displayed = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., '%s')]" % desired_text).is_displayed()
    print("Element found")

    if is_displayed:
        print("Element is visible")
    else:
        print("Element is not visible")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")
```

Comment: does `"//*[contains(., '%s')]` ignore the case of a text? it doesn't, right?

Comment: @AlanCoromano nope, but we can make it work too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible.

Comment: and if I wanted to check if multiple labels exist and visible, how would I do that? `"//*[contains(., 'label1')]  and //*[contains(., 'label2')]"`?

Comment: @AlanCoromano just loop over them one by one and issue `find_element_by_xpath()` calls for every text you want to check on the page.