# Selenium ChromeDriver with xpath using contains and lowercase

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, xpath

I'm new to selenium and xpath and I'm trying to check if a span contains certain text, while ignoring the case. I've tried referencing solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible/23388974#23388974) but without success. I have the following:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_LOCATION, options);
string name = "doe, john";
// xpath = "(//span[contains(lower-case(text()), lower-case('doe, john'))][contains(@class, 'token-label')])"
string xpath = $"(//span[contains(lower-case(text()), lower-case('{name}'))][contains(@class, 'token-label')])";
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
```

The the text in the element has "Doe, John" and therefore, fails to find the element. What is the proper way to ignore the case while using contains in xpath for selenium?

Comment: `lower-case()` is for XPath 2.0 but ChomeDriver is only XPath 1.0

Comment: Duplicate of [***case insensitive xpath contains() possible?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesnot support lower-case keyword and you could use **translate** keyword as mentioned below

```
"//span//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'"+ name + "')]".
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was unaware of the lack of chrome driver support for lower-case.