# Xpath to match case sensitive of multiple strings

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

I need to input field value in application and no unique attribute for that field. Due to that I am using text() function and it worked. This application changes slightly between vendors.

In application, for vendor1, field name is:
Physical *street* *address*

for other vendor, it is
Physical *Street* *Address*

Streed and Address are case sensitive between two vendors and due to this my script is failing.

My xPath which is working for second vendor but failing for first vendor:

```
    //tr[td[contains(text(),'Physical Street Address')]]/td//input[contains(@id, 'part1')]
```

I checked with translate but it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [case insensitive xpath contains() possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `translate()` didn't work at your end. Perhaps your code trials may have helped us to debug the issue. You can use the following solution:

```
//tr[td[translate('Physical Street Address','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')]]/td//input[contains(@id, 'part1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but I think it should work too

```
//tr[td[contains(text(),'Physical Street Address') or contains(text(),'Physical street Address')]]/td//input[contains(@id, 'part1')]
```

Comment: Sorry, forget to make 'Addres' in the second condition from the lower letter too.

Comment: Even after publishing your answer you can modify your answer by clicking on the `edit` link just below your answer which is in-between `share` and `flag` links. Let me know if you still need help to do so and need further assistance.