# Puppeteer: search for inner text case insensitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to search inner text case insensitive using puppeteer.

I've read this: [case insensitive xpath contains() possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible)

For example I have this elements:

```
<div>
 <span>Test One</span>
 <span>Test Two</span>
 <span>Test Three</span>
</div>
```

I've tried this unsuccessfully:

```
const element = await page.$x("//span//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'two')]");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XPath expression is valid, but you are returning `text()` instead of the node itself. `page.$x` expects the XPath to return an element, therefore your code does not work. To return the node you need to query for the span element.

```js
const element = await page.$x("//span[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'two')]");
```

Please note, that `text()` only works for text-only nodes. If you have mixed content (containing elements and text), you should use the string value (`.` instead of `text()`):

```js
const element = await page.$x("//span[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'two')]");
```

To compare the expressions I put them below each other:

```
//span//text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'two')]
//span[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'two')
//span[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'two')]
```

The first one is the expression (given by you) for the text of the span node. The second one queries the node itself by using `text()`. The last one uses the string value to query the node.

Comment: Do note that whenever you have mixed content (text and markup) it's better not to use text nodes but string value: this expresion `//span[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'two')]` will select this `<span> this <em>IS</em> two.</span>`

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for the comment. I added the expression to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not as pretty, but you can use `page.evaluateHandle` along with a regex to find the element:

```
const element = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div > span")).find(a => /test two/i.test(a.innerText))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to spb's, I would do:

```
const element = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
 [...document.querySelectorAll('span')].find(s => s.innerText.toLowerCase().match('two'))
)
```