# Python Selenium. How to make the "Keys" attribute work? How to find plain text on a site page? How to change page id to next automatically?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time



def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://site.ru/")
    btn_elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")
    btn_elem1.click()
    btn_elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/label/input")
    btn_elem2.click()
    btn_elem2.send_keys("login")
    btn_elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[2]/label/input")
    btn_elem3.click()
    btn_elem3.send_keys("pass")
    btn_elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a")
    btn_elem4.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get("https://site/1")
    btn_elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/img[1]")
    btn_elem5.click()

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("f").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Everything works up to a point.

The browser opens, expands. I pass to the necessary site. I go to the Login tab, enter the login and password. I’m going to another page that I don’t have access to if I’m not logged in. I open there a spoiler with hidden text.

After which I want to call "Find" via Ctrl + F, but for some reason, it doesn’t work, nothing happens. And in general, as I understand it, the keys themselves do not work. As if they were not added, although it seems to be written at the beginning of the code.

And if the necessary text is found, then take a screenshot and go to https: // site / 2, if not, then immediately go to site / 2 and search there. In total there are about ten thousand pages, probably the address of the village should be somehow made through a variable? And something like through ++ how to do it in PHP, like plus one, so that it is added every time?

Or maybe somehow it can be done differently? Search for plain text throughout the page. And if there is, then a screenshot and transition further, if not, then immediately move on. (The asterisk calls a screenshot)

```
sila = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html")
if 'Селява' in sila.text:
   action.send_keys("*")
   action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("s").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
   driver.get("https://site/+1id") (вот как это сделать?)
else:
   driver.get("https://site/+1id") (вот как это сделать?)
```

Two problems remain in general. This is how to find the text and how to make it go to the next id page.
I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Everything was fine till you wanted to call "Find" via `Ctrl + F`. This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: do you repeat the same procedures in the next page?

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to find certain text on the page, if it is found, I want to somehow save it, a screenshot, text, no matter how. The main thing is to save. Then go to the next page, which are more than a dozen thousand. Check each page above for this text, if there is one, then save, if not, then go directly to the next page.

Comment: @Chase Yes, absolutely, the same thing on every next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, selenium does not allow you to simulate `ctrl + f` conveniently. If you want to find some text on the page, you can try one of two things-

- Find said text in the `.page_source`. However, be aware that `.page_source` contains the entire page's source code. So you might end up finding your desired text in here even though it wouldn't be *visible on the frontend*.

  ```py
  if "my text" in driver.page_source:
      # "my text" is present in the source
      # do stuff
  ```
- Find *an element* that contains said text. You can also add extra steps to verify this element is actually visible. This method gives you a lot of flexibility and I'll leave the specifics up to you.

  ```py
  # Make sure you've waited long enough for the page to be loaded
  # Find by XPATH
  try:
      elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "my text")]')
      # "my text" was found in page
      # do stuff
  except NoSuchElementException:
      # Text was not found in page
  ```

  One thing to keep in mind however, is that `contains(text(), 'text')` is case sensitive. If you'd like it to be case insensitive, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8474109/10305477) (specifically the javascript preparation part, you can achieve the same with python)

Now, if you want the same operations to be performed on multiple URLs, by far the best approach would be to encapsulate the operations inside a function and call that function in a loop, passing all the URLs.

```py
def automation_func(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    btn_elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")
    btn_elem1.click()
    btn_elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/label/input")
    btn_elem2.click()
    btn_elem2.send_keys("login")
    btn_elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[2]/label/input")
    btn_elem3.click()
    btn_elem3.send_keys("pass")
    btn_elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a")
    btn_elem4.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get("https://site/1")
    btn_elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/img[1]")
    btn_elem5.click()

    # more code here
```

Now you can call this function and pass in the urls-

```py
for i in range(1, 5):
    automation_func(f"https://site.ru/{i}")
```

You may need to change up this loop according to how the URL looks like, but this is the main idea.

`f"https://site.ru/{i}"` evaluates to `https://site.ru/1` in the first iteration, then `https://site.ru/2` and so on.

Edit: This is how the code should be fitted together-

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

def automation_func(url, i):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    btn_elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")
    btn_elem1.click()
    btn_elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/label/input")
    btn_elem2.click()
    btn_elem2.send_keys("login")
    btn_elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[2]/label/input")
    btn_elem3.click()
    btn_elem3.send_keys("pass")
    btn_elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a")
    btn_elem4.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get("https://site/1")
    btn_elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/img[1]")
    btn_elem5.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    # Find the text using one of the methods here
    if "small" in driver.page_source:
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("{i}.png")


def main():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        automation_func(f"https://site.ru/{i}", i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @Chaise Thank you so much, it helped a lot. True, anyway, the error came out of me.

Comment: @Chaise I understand correctly that in the end it should look like this?

Comment: @Chaise Thanks so much for still helping me. But unfortunately it did not work. It doesn’t follow the link where just the “url” is indicated. The program goes further and does nothing, the timer is increased, checked, but unfortunately - no.

Comment: @Chaise or should I write the site in both places instead of "url"? In lines 9 and 12

Comment: @Chaise I don’t know if it matters, but in line 12 I go to the main page to just log in to the site, since without this you can’t get to the link where you already need to change the id.

Comment: @Chaise Only from the 24th line is the first link used that should change. I tried and swapped these lines, I thought it might work, but no, then the code just stops anyway in the same place.