# Search an element by a specific word in DOM with contains but case Insensitive, dosen't work using lower-case() XPATH 2.0

Tags: javascript, python, xml, selenium, xpath

Given this element :

```
<div class="block-level-tooltip color_title ellipsis-tooltip" title="RATE">RED Infinity 25 Rate</div>
```

I'm trying to do a xpath slector that is not case sensitive to title attribute value or text value that contains the word 'rate'

What I've tried, but dosen't seem to find anything:

P.S. Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible/23388974#23388974)

```
//*[(contains(lower-case(@title), 'rate')) or (contains(lower-case(text()), 'rate'))]
```

Comment: Give ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read, it will help you improve your questions.

Comment: Ok, sure, but, did I miss any details that would help reproduce the request ? I'm not trying to be rude but, I don't see what else i can improve at this, besides the title.

Comment: `fn:lower-case` is from XPath 2.0. You cannot use it in Selenium. Try workaround `//*[(contains(@title, 'rate') or contains(@title, 'RATE')) or (contains(., 'rate') or contains(., 'RATE'))]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XPath 2.0, you can use `matches` with regex

try `//*[matches(@title, 'rate', 'i')]`

for both title and inner text

`//*[matches(@title, 'rate', 'i') or matches(., 'rate', 'i')]`