# Selenium - How to find an element by part of the placeholder value?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, placeholder

Is there any way to find an element by a part of the placeholder value? And ideally, case insensitive.

`<input id="id-9" placeholder="some TEXT">`

Search by the following function doesn't work

`browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@placeholder='some te']")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `contains` instead of `equals`, as following:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@placeholder,'some te')]")
```

To make it case-insensitive you can use `translate` function, as following:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input/@placeholder[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'some te')]")
```

Case-insensitive `contains` Xpath is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible)

Comment: You can also use css:
`input[placeholder^="some te"]`

Comment: Right, `^` in css is similar to `contains` in XPath. But this question was about XPath, not CSS

Comment: @zaki98 oh, thanks a lot! Does `^` also work for case insensitive search?

Comment: @Mike AFAIK no, similarly to regular `contains` in XPath.

Comment: @Mike i added an answer since it may help other people too

Answer (score 2):

@Prophet's answer is good, but I wanted to add CSS case too since it may be helpful.
You can use `^=` to search for attributes starting with certain keyword and `$=` for attribute starting with certain keywrd and `*=` for attribute containing a keyword.

```py
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder*="some te"]')
```

You can make it case-insensitive by adding `i` [before closing the bracket](https://caniuse.com/css-case-insensitive)

```py
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder*="some te" i]')
```

Comment: Thank you! But is everything correct? I'm getting the error `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

Comment: @Mike really sorry i had a syntax error and i used the wrong selector it should be working now i tested it