# Click on parent element based on two conditions in child elements Selenium Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium 4.8 in .NET 6, I have the following html structure to parse.

```
<ul class="search-results">
  <li>
    <a href=//to somewhere>
      <span class="book-desc">
       <div class="book-title">some title</div>
       <span class="book-author">some author</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to find and click on the right li where the book-title matches my variable input (ideally ignore sentence case too) AND the book author also matches my variable input. So far I'm not getting that xpath syntax correct. I've tried different variations of something along these lines:

```
var matchingBooks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath($"//li[.//span[@class='book-author' and text()='{b.Authors}' and @class='book-title' and text()='{b.Title}']]"));
```

then I check if matchingBooks has a length before clicking on the first element. But matchingBooks is always coming back as 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class="book-author"` belongs to `span` while `class="book-title"` belongs to `div` child element.
Also it cane be extra spaces additionally to the text, so it's better to use `contains` instead of exact `equals` validation.
So, instead of `"//li[.//span[@class='book-author' and text()='{b.Authors}' and @class='book-title' and text()='{b.Title}']]"` please try this:

```cs
"//li[.//span[@class='book-author' and(contains(text(),'{b.Authors}'))] and .//div[@class='book-title' and(contains(text(),'{b.Title}'))]]"
```

**UPD**
The following XPath should work. This is a example specific XPath I tried and it worked `"//li[.//span[@class='book-author' and(contains(text(),'anima'))] and .//div[@class='book-title' and(contains(text(),'Coloring'))]]"` for `blood of the fold` search input.
Also, I guess you should click on `a` element inside the `li`, not on the `li` itself. So, it's try to click the following element:

```cs
"//li[.//span[@class='book-author' and(contains(text(),'{b.Authors}'))] and .//div[@class='book-title' and(contains(text(),'{b.Title}'))]]//a"
```

Comment: got an exception. Unable to locate element with....

Comment: Can you share a link? we are missing basic debugging details.

Comment: {"invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //li[.//span[@class='book-author' and(contains(text(),'Terry Goodkind'))] and .//div[@class='book-title' and(contains(text(),'Blood of the Fold'))]]] because of the following error:\nSyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//li[.//span[@class='book-author' and(contains(text(),'Terry Goodkind'))] and .//div[@class='book-title' and(contains(text(),'Blood of the Fold'))]]]' is not a valid XPath expression.\n  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.126)"}

Comment: Not the error trace, a link to the page you working on

Comment: https://openlibrary.org/works/OL2010487W/Blood_of_the_fold added a picture too. Basically, I'm entering title and author in the header search field then parsing that dropdown response

Comment: In the shared page no results appearing below the `ul class="search-results"` element. No elements with class name `class="book-desc"` etc

Comment: it's in the popover of the main search in the navbar, not in any one page.

Comment: You are right, it was extra `]`. Now I fixed it. Please see the updated answer

Comment: I think I need to do case insensitive. The system wrote in "Blood of the Fold" and it found 0 probably because the title in the html is "Blood of the fold"

Comment: Well, you will have to pass text exactly in the case sensitive way it appears in web elements. Alternatively you will have to use `translate` function as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474031/case-insensitive-xpath-contains-possible since Selenium supports xpath 1.0 only